# Long delay on document load with wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, google-chrome, dom, optimization

I'm working on optimizing a site and I've been able to get all of the pages to load in around 2 seconds just by optimizing the images with photoshop but, I have one page that doesn't seem to react like the rest. When I open up the developer tools in Chrome and watch the waterfall timeline of the loading elements it shows that there is a lag of over 3 seconds just to load the document. The fastest time I've ever been able to get the page to load is around 7 seconds, which is way longer than it should be since the page is only 895 kB.

Is this a server issue or is there some faulty code in the specific page? It makes me wonder because other pages on the same website load much faster even though their size is greater. Any help from you would be awesome!

Link to webpage: http://egi.utah.edu/corporate-associate-program/corporate-associate-list/

[image: Screenshot of developer tools]

Comment: Since most of the overhead is the browser "waiting" for a response from the server, are there any heavy database queries that might be happening on this page or data that gets loaded from some external resource in order to render the page on the server?

Comment: I would guess whatever thing is being "listed" in this page is doing a heavy database query. Try limiting it to the first X results, and the page may load faster. (Then you may have to have a paging structure of some sort)

Comment: @drew010 Not that I know of... It's all just static content on that page.

Comment: it's wordpress, I'm sure there are database queries for posts in loops there, don't lie to us. maybe limit those queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cache plugin probably will solve your problem since no query will be called to db unless something in the page changed.

I used 2 of them and both speed up sites. (But only use one, you cant use both at the same time.)

1. Wp-rocket http://wp-rocket.me/
2. Wordpress super cache https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with your input. It turns out that it was a image slider plugin (FlexSlider) that was re-generating the images to fit the size of the element which was slowing it down so much. There were 7 large images that it re-generated on the server side as the page was requested. All I had to do was stop the plugin from resizing the images by leaving it to the default setting and I wrote some javascript to do the same thing but locally and it sped up the loading time drastically. It's now loading at under 3 seconds when it was loading at around 10.

Thanks [@drew010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892493/drew010)

Comment: Great, still recommend to use cache plugin. The time load of the page is 5.5 seconds (unless its on a different link now, or maybe my internet is slow)